# how to correct the error "Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' "

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to send two values to two cells in an excel ALREADY CREATED, which has the name see.xlsx ... but it turns out that I get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open consulta.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:343 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\f.php(15): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load('see.xlsx') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\importexcel\lib\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 343
```

my excel file I have stored on my desktop, and I'm using excel 2010

the code is the following:

f.php

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 set_time_limit(0);

 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
 set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'lib/PHPExcel/');

 require_once 'lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
 $fileType = 'Excel2007';
 $fileName = 'see.xlsx';

 // Read the file
 $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
 $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

 // Change the file
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!');

 // Write the file
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
 $objWriter->save($fileName);

 ?>
```

Comment: The error could not be more specific: 'Could not open consulta.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ - it is trying to load the file from you local XAMP, you mention yourself the Excel file is your Windows Desktop. Either configure the path pointing to the the desktop, or move the fie to the expected path.

Comment: As @OmarGonzalez said, the path looks incorrect. It looks like perhaps that you are using a relative path to the file with the code. Most likely if you move the file to the same folder as this php file, or give the full path, not the file name, it will work.

Comment: you were right, I had to put the excel where the location will send me. load and execute successfully, but then I had the excel open and try to upload information but it could not be done because according to the error that comes out, the excel must be closed ... there will be some way that the excel can be open and can upload information ?